# How to create a DGS GraphQL Subscription to an ActiveMQ Topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, spring-integration, netflix-dgs

I have a bit of a complicated technology stack. I am leveraging Netflix DGS to provide a GraphQL service. Behind the scenes are a bunch of JMS components sending and receiving data from various services. I have everything working outside of a GraphQL subscription.

Specifically what I am trying to do is is create a GraphQL subscription for messages from an ActiveMQ topic.

So I have a SubscriptionDataFetcher as follows:

```java
@DgsComponent
public class SurveyResultsSubscriptionDataFetcher {

    private final Publisher<SurveyResult> surveyResultsReactiveSource;

    @Autowired
    public SurveyResultsSubscriptionDataFetcher(Publisher<SurveyResult> surveyResultsReactiveSource) {
        this.surveyResultsReactiveSource = surveyResultsReactiveSource;
    }

    @DgsData(parentType = DgsConstants.SUBSCRIPTION.TYPE_NAME, field = DgsConstants.SUBSCRIPTION.SurveyResultStream)
    public Publisher<SurveyResult> surveyResults() {
        return surveyResultsReactiveSource;
    }
}
```

Inside my Spring configuration, I am using the following Spring Integration Flow:

```java
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Publisher<SurveyResult> surveyResultsReactiveSource() {
    SurveyResultMessageConverter converter = new SurveyResultMessageConverter();

    return Flux.from(
            IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory()).destination(surveyDestination))
                    .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
                    .log()
                    .toReactivePublisher())
            .map((message) -> converter.fromMessage(message, SurveyResult.class));
}
```

I will say a few things:

1. I have a separate `@JmsListener` that is receiving these messages off the topic
2. I do **not** see more than one consumer, even after a web socket connection is established.
3. If I hook up a Mongo Reactive Spring Data Repository to this GraphQL subscription, data is received by the client.

When I connect the client to the subscription, I see the following logs:

```
PublishSubscribeChannel      : Channel 'unknown.channel.name' has 1 subscriber(s).
DgsWebSocketHandler          : Subscription started for 1
```

I suspect that the message listener container isn't activated when the web socket connection is established. Am I supposed to "activate" the channel adapter? What am I missing?

Tech Stack:

```
    // spring boots - version 2.4.3
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration"
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'

    // spring integration
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-jms', version: '5.4.4'

    // dgs
    implementation "com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter:3.10.2"
    implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-subscriptions-websockets-autoconfigure:3.10.2'
```

**Update 1:**

For what its worth, if I update the subscription to the following I get results on the client side.

```
    @DgsData(parentType = DgsConstants.SUBSCRIPTION.TYPE_NAME, field = DgsConstants.SUBSCRIPTION.SurveyResultStream)
    public Publisher<SurveyResult> surveyResults() {
        // repository is a ReactiveMongoRepository
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

Update 2:

This is the finalized bean in case it helps someone out based on accepted solution. I needed the listener on a topic, not a queue.

```java
    @Bean
    public Publisher<Message<SurveyResult>> surveyResultsReactiveSource() {
        SurveyResultMessageConverter converter = new SurveyResultMessageConverter();

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                Jms.container(connectionFactory(), surveyDestination).pubSubDomain(true))
                .jmsMessageConverter(converter))
                .toReactivePublisher();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return Flux.from(
        IntegrationFlows.from(
```

And the framework just doesn't see that inner `IntegrationFlow` instance to parse and register properly.

To make it working you need to consider to declare that `IntegrationFlow` as a top-level bean.

Something like this:

```
@Bean
public Publisher<Message<SurveyResult>> surveyResultsReactiveSource() {  
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory()).destination(surveyDestination))
                    .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
                    .transform([transform to SurveyResult])
                    .toReactivePublisher();
}
```

Now the framework knows that this logical `IntegrationFlow` container has to be parsed and all the beans have to be registered and started.

You probably need to rethink your `SurveyResultMessageConverter` logic to a plain `transform()` if you can't supply a `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter` with your converter.

Then in your `SurveyResultsSubscriptionDataFetcher` you just need to have:

```
 return surveyResultsReactiveSource.map(Message::getPayload);
```

Comment: Artem, that was it! Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I also updated the question with the updated solution based on your guidance. Thanks!